# Error : can't load file in dist when run electron in angular project

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder

I use electron JS in my angular project but I had this error when run electron

[image]

this file is found in dist folder when make build , I use "target": "es5", and base href './'

Comment: Can you try to remove the `<base href="/">` and try again

Comment: the same result

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same errors and changed the  to 
This makes sense since the js module file sits inside the dist folder and not the root folder.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31831028)